# Segmentation fault when trying to get lowest number from user inputted array

Tags: c, arrays, segmentation-fault

I'm making a program that calculates the average of user inputted tests, after the user has inputted the number of tests, the user then has to input every grade for the number of tests inputted, after that the program will then read into the array of grades inputted then get the lowest grade, after that the program will calculate the average, then output that, then output the lowest grade, then call function "letter();" to get the letter grade based on the value on the average. but when it goes into getting the lowest number from the array it gives me a segmentation fault that I can't fix

I have tried to redo that part of the code to no avail

```
#include <stdio.h>

void letter();

int average;

int main()
{
    int a[100], i, sum = 0, num, lowest, test;

    printf("Enter the numbers of tests: ");
    scanf("%d", &test);

    while (test > 100 || test <= 0)
    {
        printf("Error! The number of tests should be in range of (1 to 100).\n");
        printf("Enter the number again: ");
        scanf("%d", &test);
    }

    for(i = 0; i < test; ++i)
    {
        printf("%d. Enter grade for this test: ", i+1);
        scanf("%d", &a[i]);
        sum += a[i];
    }

    lowest = a[0];

    for (i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        if (a[i] < lowest)
        {
            lowest = a[i];
        }
    }

    average = sum / test;
    printf("Average = %d", average);

   return (0);
}

void letter()
{
    if (average == 0 || average <= 60)
    {
        printf("Your average is a F. \n");
    }

    else if (average <= 70 || average >= 61)
    {
        printf("Your average is a D. \n");
    }

    else if (average <= 80 || average >= 71)
    {
        printf("Your average is a C. \n");
    }

    else if (average <= 90 || average >= 81)
    {
        printf("Your average is a B. \n");
    }

    else if (average <= 100 || average >= 91)
    {
        printf("Your average is a A. \n");
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

I added

```
printf("Your average is: %d \n", average);

printf("The lowest grade is: %d \n", lowest);

letter();
```

after

```
average = sum / test;
```

and changed the letter function to this but doesnt give me correct letter grade with average

```
void letter()
{
    if (average >= 0 || average <= 59)
    {
        printf("Your average is a F. \n");
    }

    else if (average >= 60 || average <= 69)
    {
        printf("Your average is a D. \n");
    }

    else if (average >= 70 || average <= 79)
    {
        printf("Your average is a C. \n");
    }

    else if (average >= 80 || average <= 89)
    {
        printf("Your average is a B. \n");
    }

    else if (average >= 90 || average <= 99)
    {
        printf("Your average is a A. \n");
    }
}
```

**EDIT #2**
Changed letter function to this, now it works, thanks everyone for you help and taking your time to help me out.

```
void letter()
{
    if (average == 0 && average <= 60)
    {
        printf("Your average is a F. \n");
    }

    else if (average <= 70 && average >= 61)
    {
        printf("Your average is a D. \n");
    }

    else if (average <= 80 && average >= 71)
    {
        printf("Your average is a C. \n");
    }

    else if (average <= 90 && average >= 81)
    {
        printf("Your average is a B. \n");
    }

    else if (average <= 100 && average >= 91)
    {
        printf("Your average is a A. \n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try to run it through a debugger?

Comment: Ummm..where are you calling `letter()`?

Comment: Style suggestion: `return (0);`.. please don't make `return` statement look like a function.

Comment: You don't need an array to find the lowest value or the average.

Comment: Why don't you start solving step by step, use lot of printing so you know till what step you have reached.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem that I see is

```
 for (i = 0; i < num; i++)
```

here, `num` is used unintialized. If you try to use the value of a variable which

- is never initialized
- can have trap representation
- never has the address taken

it invokes [undefined behavior.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)

**Solution:** You'd want to use `test` as the loop counter.

And also, in your code, you never made a call to `letter()`.

[A modified version of your code which prints the expected output.](https://ideone.com/5IroTd)

Comment: Ohh I see, thank you, I changed it and it works, I added a printf to display the average and lowest grade and called letter(); but the letter grades do not display correctly if the average is 61 then it displays F but if its 62 then it is still a F but not a D

Comment: @Detsibli Well, I get a `D` for average of 61, with the first version of your code.

Answer (score 3):

The variable `num` is allocated on stack and and it is not initialised so it will have garbage value.
You are using it in below `for` loop. Hence if `num` is arbitrarily greater than or equal to 100, you would try to access `a[num]` which is array out of bound access and **can** result in crash. You should use `test` instead of `num` in below for loop.

```
for (i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        if (a[i] < lowest)
        {
            lowest = a[i];
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The variable `num` is not initialized and it is used in the `for` loop

```
for (i = 0; i < num; i++)
```

This leads to [undefined behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/behavior). The segmentation fault is probably caused by the fact that the uninitialized value of `num` used as an index to array `a` leads to an out of bounds memory access in the below check.

```
 if (a[i] < lowest)
```

Answer (score 2):

At the time you enter loop

```
for (i = 0; i < num; i++) {
    if (a[i] < lowest)
```

your variable `num` is not initialized. This is undefined behaviour, probably leading to a segfault due to a value of `i` larger than `99` then.

Write `for (i = 0; i < test; i++)` instead.